# Need to show group of images on mouse hover an image using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How Can I show group of images on mouse hover an image using jQuery?

Please provide any links or example code.

Answer (score 0):

**To have the image displayed when moused over but then hide when not moused over:**

```
  <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showIt(imgsrc)
{
document.getElementById('imageshow').src=imgsrc;
document.getElementById('imageshow').style.display='block';
}

function hideIt()
{
document.getElementById('imageshow').style.display='none';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="image1.jpg" onmouseover="showIt(this.src)" onmouseout="hideIt()"><br>
<img src="image2.jpg" onmouseover="showIt(this.src)" onmouseout="hideIt()">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<img src="" id="imageshow" style="display:none">
</body>
</html>
```

**To have it show a default image even when you aren't moused over an image, but then show an image if you are moused over it:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showIt(imgsrc)
{
document.getElementById('imageshow').src=imgsrc;
}

function hideIt()
{
document.getElementById('imageshow').src="default.jpg";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="image1.jpg" onmouseover="showIt(this.src)" onmouseout="hideIt()"><br>
<img src="image2.jpg" onmouseover="showIt(this.src)" onmouseout="hideIt()">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<img src="default.jpg" id="imageshow">
</body>
</html>
```

**To have it show an image when you mouseover it and then keep showing the last image even when you mouseout of it :**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showIt(imgsrc)
{
document.getElementById('imageshow').src=imgsrc;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="image1.jpg" onmouseover="showIt(this.src)"><br>
<img src="image2.jpg" onmouseover="showIt(this.src)">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<img src="default.jpg" id="imageshow">
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I want to show group of images in a popup with adjacent to the actual image and hide the pop up when mouseout. I do not want to use any Div.